# How to mock mongodb when it is called from another function?

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking, mongomock

I need help while mocking mongodb. I am using [mongomock](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock) to mock mongodb.

My project structure is:

> -- my_mongo.py
>   -- code.py
>   -- my_test.py

**my_mongo.py** has :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

 def get_db():
   client = MongoClient(os.environ['MONGODB_URI'])
   db = client['my_db']
   return db

 def insert(id, data):
     return get_db().results.insert_one(
          {
          "id": id,
          "data":df.to_json(),
          }).id
```

and **code.py** has

```
import my_mongo

def action():
    #do somethings
    my_mongo.insert(id, data)
```

and **my_test.py** has

```
import mongomock
import my_mongo
from unittest import mock


with patch.object(my_mongo.get_db().client, "client",  mongomock.MongoClient()):
    import code

def test_action_1():
    my_mongo.insert = mock.Mock(return_value=1)
    code.action()   

def test_action_2():
     with patch.object(my_mongo.get_db(), "get_db", mongomock.MongoClient().db):
     code.action()
```

It throws pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError for both tests. So, It still goes into the insert_one() method in my_mongo.py. 
I expect in test_action_1 my_mongo.insert returns 1, but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what `mongomock` is for, but it looks like it's for mocking an entire mongo database and not actually using python mocking. I'm going to answer without including `mongomock` since I don't think you really need it, so you can take that for what it's worth.

There were a few issues:

1. Calling `patch.object` will patch the given method on whatever object you give it. If you call `get_db` in the test, then `code.action` calls `get_db`, those are 2 different objects. Maybe this works? But I'm skeptical, so I just changed it.
2. Don't use `code` as your module name. That's already a module included with python.
3. `code.action` was missing args and a return statement.

You'll also notice that I changed how and what was being mocked to illustrate different ways to accomplish the mocking. Test 1 mocks the `insert` call with a function decorator. Test 2 mocks the `get_db` call with a `contextmanager`. Either is correct, just showing that you have options.

Here's the finished product:

---

my_mongo.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def get_db():
    client = MongoClient(os.environ['MONGODB_URI'])
    db = client['my_db']
    return db

def insert(id, data):
    return get_db().results.insert_one({"id": id, "data":data.to_json()}).id  # df was undefined, updated to data
```

---

my_code.py:

```
import my_mongo

# I added id and data args. They were undefined
def action(id, data):
    return my_mongo.insert(id, data)  # I added a return here
```

---

my_test.py

```
from unittest import mock

import my_code

# I removed the contextmanager import. Nothing is being evaluated here that would
# need to be patched, so I'm pretty certain it has no effect

@mock.patch('my_mongo.insert')
def test_action_1(mock_insert):
    expected_id = 1
    mock_insert.return_value = expected_id
    ret = my_code.action(expected_id, mock.Mock())
    assert ret == expected_id

def test_action_2():
    with mock.patch('my_mongo.get_db') as mock_get_db:
        expected_id = 'some id'
        mock_db = mock.Mock()
        mock_db.results.insert_one.return_value.id = expected_id
        mock_get_db.return_value = mock_db
        ret = my_code.action(expected_id, mock.Mock())
    assert ret == expected_id
```

Answer (score 0):

That line of code for patching mongodb is wrong. Instead of using `patch.object(my_mongo.get_db(), "get_db", mongomock.MongoClient().db)`, you should use `patch.object("my_mongo.get_db", return_value=mongomock.MongoClient()['my_db'])`.

---

Following is the complete runable code for your example:

**my_test.py**

```
import mongomock
from unittest.mock import patch

import my_code
import my_mongo


def test_action_2():
    mocked_mongo = mongomock.MongoClient()
    with patch("my_mongo.get_db", return_value=mongomock.MongoClient()['my_db']):
        my_code.action()
        assert mocked_mongo.my_db.results.count_documents({'id': 'some_id'}) == 1
```

**my_mongo.py**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def get_db():
    client = MongoClient(os.environ['MONGODB_URI'])
    db = client['my_db']
    return db

def insert(id, data):
    return get_db().results.insert_one(
        {
            "id": id,
            "data": data,
        })
```

**my_code.py**

```
import my_mongo

def action():
    #do somethings
    return my_mongo.insert('some_id', '{"a": 3}')
```